# How to unittest a dictionary that contains keys with string values and keys that are dictionaries?

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, key

I am trying to unit-test, within python, a dictionary that contains keys with string values and keys with dictionary values, however, I don't know a good way of doing this. Below is an example:

```
x = {'type': 'example', 'color': 'blue', 'entries_dict':{'clock':'c', 'id': 1}}
y = {'color': 'blue', 'entries_dict':{'id': 1, 'clock':'c'}, 'type': 'example'}
self.assertDictEqual(x, y)
```

The above example is what I want to accomplish but don't know how. A recursive way would be better since there is more information in my actual dictionaries than the example I posted above.

Comment: self.assertEqual(x, y)

Comment: I have done assertEqual, but occasionally it will report that the test failed because the order of the keys in the dictionary are not set.

Comment: assertEqual should work according to docs here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual
Can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I have not used Python 3.7, but prior to that version, dictionaries keys are not in any order.

Comment: clearly the code work and should work, it is something else that not given.

Comment: Here is the exact error message when using asserEqual: 
AssertionError: {'4': {'previous_pto': 80.0, 'vacation_dedu[4460 chars]0.0}} != {'2': {'previous_pto': 80.0, 'vacation_dedu[4460 chars]0.0}}
Diff is 8593 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.